# MVC Routing and session

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am developing a MVC application with Windows authentication. We have a login module developed for windows auth, so when any user tries to access this application is redirected to the login page for windows auth, hosted elsewhere. After it validates user, it returns user information and here I am creating session for the user. This works fine.

Now consider 2 scenarios
1. if user tries to access http://localhost:63145/Home/Index , he is redirected to login page and it return the control back to Index method of **Home Controller where I create session.**

2. if user tries to access http://localhost:63145/Product/Index, , he is redirected to login page and it return the control back to Index method of **Product controller where I am not creating any session.**

So in case 2, user's sessions are not created. What should be the better approach here?

Comment: What do you mean by  _user's sessions are not created_ ? Are you not able access the `Session` variable like `Session["SomeItem"] = "SomeValue"` ?

Comment: Why are you not adding the value to `Session` in the Login POST method?

Comment: I don't have login page in my project, as mentioned it is hosted in different domain
@mihir, I mean that, code for creating session is in HomeController Index action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `BaseController` like this;

```
public class BaseController : Controller
    {
        protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            InitAppController(filterContext);
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }

        // Redirect to login page if user's session is not valid.
        public void InitAppController(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            if (/* Check Session Condition Here */)
            {
                filterContext.Result = RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
            }
        }
    }
```

Then, change all of your controllers;

`HomeController : Controller` to `HomeController : BaseController`

`ProductController : Controller` to `ProductController : BaseController`